# How to checked/unchecked multilevel checkboxes via jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox, checked

```
<div width="100%">
<ul>
    <li><label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox" id="checkbox" />
    </label>
    <strong>Select All        </strong>
     <ul>
     <li>&nbsp;
     <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox2" id="checkbox2" />Catalog</li>
</ul>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox4" id="checkbox4" /> 
    <strong>Orgnisation</strong>
<ul>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox5" id="checkbox5" />
    Device</li>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox8" id="checkbox8" />
    Gadgets</li>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox9" id="checkbox9" />Pour</li>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox10" id="checkbox10" /> 
    <strong>SubOrg</strong>
<ul>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox11" id="checkbox11" />
    123              </li>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox12" id="checkbox12" />
    456</li>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox13" id="checkbox13" /> 
    789</li>
</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
    </li>
    <li><input type="checkbox" name="checkbox3" id="checkbox3" />
    <strong>Orgnisation1</strong>&nbsp;
<ul>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox6" id="checkbox6" />
    Device1</li>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox7" id="checkbox7" />
    Gadgets1</li>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox14" id="checkbox14" />
    Pour1</li>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox15" id="checkbox15" />
    <strong>SubOrg </strong>
    <ul>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox16" id="checkbox16" />
    123a </li>
    <li>
    456a</li>
    <li>
    <input type="checkbox" name="checkbox18" id="checkbox18" />
    789a</li>
</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I am newbie in JQuery field and want to achieved whatever I present in following code. It can be "N" number of level. It is just like a tree. When I click on top level(select all) its checked/unchecked all below checkbox. Whenever I click on "orgnisation" its select all below one and same for "suborg". Please help me with an example. I want a genric code if I removed one or two level I not need to modify my js file.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, **[Chris Coyer](http://chriscoyier.net)** of **[CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/)** wrote a very good article about this subject. You can see it **[here](http://css-tricks.com/13467-indeterminate-checkboxes/)**. [**Example**](http://css-tricks.com/examples/IndeterminateCheckboxes/).

Comment: Thanks rikudo, I am looking for exactly same thing.

Comment: one question in general, Why i get -1 for this question.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/xj7NY/1/

Basically you attach the click() event to the "select all" checkbox, check you see its state (checked or not) and apply the changes to all of the checkboxes in the second container (the `label` element in this example) accordingly.

Comment: Thanks sliverstrike, your answer is very helpful, but i am looking for multilevel or tree level things